# Using python itertools to find all possible combinations of sublist elements that sums to target values

Tags: python, loops, iteration, combinations, python-itertools

Please, I have gone through already answered questions but can't find answers. I am fairly new to python.

My question is:

For example, given that:

**myList** = [[2,4], [1,3], [3,5], [1,4]]

How can I use python itertools/combinations to iterate through the nested list (**myList**) such that I can find all possible combinations of **myList** elements (that is, the sublists) whose zero-indices (that is, **myList**[**i**][0]) and first-indices (that is, **myList**[**i**][1]) sums up to 4 and 11, respectively (where **i** in range (len(**myList**)).

From **myList** I want to find all possible combinations of the sublists that meets the two conditions below:

sum(**myList**[i][0]) == 4 and
sum(**myList**[i][1]) == 11   (where **i** in range (len(**myList**))

So, from **myList** I want to get the output as:

Output: [[[2,4], [1,3], [1,4]], [any other combinations_1], [any other combinations_2], [and so on]]

Please, I would appreciate any assistance you could provide. Thanks.

Comment: So you want to take any subset of the `myList` elements - there could be any number of them, from 0 up to all of them?

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Yes, please, Thanks

Comment: Please properly format code, [click here to learn how](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from itertools import combinations

myList = [[2,4], [1,3], [3,5], [1,4]]

combos = [
    x for i in range(1, len(myList)+1)
    for x in combinations(myList, i)
    if sum(list(zip(*x))[0]) == 4 and sum(list(zip(*x))[1]) == 11
]
```

Comment: No problem. The tricky part was getting all the brackets in the `zip` part correct. :-)